# Visualforce Error List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, list

I have a visualforce page which returns the error: Visualforce Error List index out of bounds: 0 , I figured out that my list is empty but how kan ik render my visualforce page without the empty list het is part of my visuaforce page and my

**controller:**

```
  public with sharing class oppList {

    public List<Opportunity> myOpp {get;set;}
    public String currentRecordId {get;set;}

    public oppList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

   myOpp = [SELECT (SELECT Name,ExpirationDate,TotalPrice,status,CreatedDate FROM Quotes ORDER by Name), Name,StageName, CloseDate , Amount,Contact__r.Name,owner.Name,Probability,Account.Name  FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.Id=:currentRecordId ORDER by Name]; 
        Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'inline; filename='+myOpp[0].Account.name+'-'+date.today().format()+'.pdf');
    } 
    public List<Opportunity> getOpp() {     
        if(!myOpp.isEmpty()){return myOpp;}
       else return null;
      }    
}
```

**visual force**

```
   <apex:outputtext rendered="{!IF(Opp!=null,true, false)}">
                        <apex:repeat var="op" value="{!Opp}">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!op.StageName != 'Closed Won'}">
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!op.StageName != 'Closed Lost'}">
                            <table style="border: 0;margin:0px">
                                <tr style="border: 0;font-weight:bold;"><td width="200">Name </td><td width="115">Owner </td><td width="70">Stage</td><td width="50">
                                  Closed</td><td width="50">Amount</td><td width="30">Prob.</td><td width="150">Contact</td></tr> 
                                <tr style="border: 0;"><td width="200">{!op.Name} </td><td width="115">{!op.Owner.Name} </td><td width="70">{!op.StageName}</td><td width="50"><apex:outputText value="{0,date, dd/MM/yy}">
                                  <apex:param value="{!op.CloseDate}" /></apex:outputText></td><td width="50">€&nbsp;{!op.Amount}</td><td width="30">{!op.Probability}%</td><td width="150">{!op.Contact__r.Name}</td></tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="border: 0;">
                                <tr style="border: 0;font-weight:bold;"><td width="200"><apex:outputText >Open Quotes:</apex:outputText></td><td width="50">ExpDate</td><td width="62">status</td><td width="70">Send</td><td width="200">TotalPrice</td></tr>     
                            <apex:repeat var="oq" value="{!Op.Quotes}">
                            <tr style="border: 0;"><td width="200"><apex:outputText >{!oq.Name}</apex:outputText></td><td width="50"><apex:outputText value="{0,date, dd/MM/yy}"><apex:param value="{!oq.ExpirationDate}" /></apex:outputText></td><td width="62">{!oq.status}</td><td width="70"><apex:outputText value="{0,date, dd/MM/yy}"><apex:param value="{!oq.CreatedDate}" /></apex:outputText></td><td width="200"><apex:outputText >€ &nbsp;{!oq.TotalPrice}</apex:outputText></td></tr>     
                            </apex:repeat>  
                            </table>
                         </apex:outputPanel>
                         </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:repeat>
                      </apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Did you checked, your getting  currentRecordId  in apex class ?

Comment: @Nithesh If i have opportunities it works fine my problem is when the list is empty

Comment: Please note you can ***always*** replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`.

Comment: There is no result in list "myOpp" , And your trying to get value from null list.

Comment: Also please note the proper way to get `currentRecordId` is just `controller.getId()`. It might *work* to get this data via parameters, but the standard controller is more concise and direct.

Comment: Check   if(myOpp.size()>0)  before perform Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders() ....

Comment: @NITHESHK Your solution worked Thanks please show this as an answer so I can check it as correct. Thanks Adrian for the notes.

Comment: @Jenssen yes sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Should be better if check the size of the list before accessing value of the list myOpp index zero.

```
if(myOpp.size()>0) {
    Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 
        'inline; filename='+myOpp[0].Account.name+'-'+date.today().format()+'.pdf');
}
```